# Install the static files from a command prompt

Tags: magento, magento2

I would like to install the static files from a command prompt.

I type in `cmd`

```
cd C:/xampp/htdocs/magento.
```

Inside the directory I type the command

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

Which gives me:

> could not be found.

Can anyon give me an advice on this?

Comment: here cd C:/xampp/htdocs/magento your magento install am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Add php to PATH variable, or use absolute path for php like :
C:\xampp\bin\php\php5.6.31\php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE

Answer (score 0):

use : /opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento s:static-content:deploy -f